# How to install CVXPY / SCS to use with GPU?

Tags: python, azure, docker, nvidia, cvxpy

All the dependencies are installed in a docker container, but when I run the example with GPU=True it returns "Status: Unbounded" and with GPU=False it works ok. The scs-python GPU tests return "Status: Unbounded". Also, nvidia-smi displays GPU usage. What might be the issue?

Dockerfile: https://gist.github.com/Cerebrock/eef5d33ece1782d3efdf0b35d29fb48e

Example: https://gist.github.com/Cerebrock/885023ec2faf1d1c6bf9b1a4df12df36

OS: Ubuntu 16.04 on Azure, image NVIDIA GPU Cloud image, NVIDIA Tesla P100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and I was able to fix it building SCS-PYTHON like:

```
python3 setup.py install --scs --gpu --int
```

If you look at the setup.py help it says:

> GPU code always uses 32 bit ints

```
python3 setup.py install --help
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this via pip?

Comment: You can install it with pip, but GPU won't be enabled.